# Creating a form that only show form fields for editing the node title, body, and any fields created using the field API

Tags: forms

I have created a content type with some field API fields.

How can I create a edit form that allows to edit just the title, the node body, and those fields?

The normal node edit form contains extra form fields that are not necessary for my purpose (i.e. they are not for editing the parts of a node I listed).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Do you mean accessing them programmatically? If it is so, from which hook/function do you need to access them?

Comment: @kiamlaluno ya programmatically ...
i tried with drupal_get_form(), but its gives to much of unwanted things

Comment: @SoniKishan Use `drupal_get_form` with your content type id.

Comment: @SumitMadan if i use drupal_get_form() than i have to go through so many filters, what i want is just form fields. (which can have field type,default value, options, etc)..

Comment: check this I just created http://drupalwithphp.blogspot.in/2013/01/get-form-array-of-any-content-type-in.html ;)

Comment: @SumitMadan hey bro i don't want html rendered thing..

Comment: no $form is a form array in callback function you can use code anywhere.

Comment: do print_r($form); it's giving more than 10k line of codes ...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?  I am not really sure what you mean by "getting the form fields".  It could mean a few different things.

Comment: @MPD Let's take one instance ,
if i have content type with title , body , some fields like , radios , checkboxes, select etc...
now if i do drupal_get_form('contenttype_node_form'); it ll give me entire structure in array including other info's like comments, revisions, menu etc..
i just want structure of title , body , some fields like , radios , checkboxes, select in array..
i hope u got what i m trying to achieve..

Comment: @SoniKishan Don't use `print_r()` then ;) The [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) has a nice function called `dpm()` which prints a collapsed JS representation of the variable that you can navigate through. That will make debugging much easier

Comment: What are you trying to do with this information, though?

Comment: @MPD i m creating web service for the (cck) content types, which will be used in android app..

Answer (score 1):

I get you want to show a form where the users can enter the values for the fields implemented using the field API, the node body, and the title; other form fields should not be shown.

Using the following code, you can achieve what you want.

```
function mymodule_node_form($form, $form_state, $node) {
  global $user;

  if (!isset($form_state['node'])) {
    if (!isset($node->title)) {
      $node->title = NULL;
    }
    node_object_prepare($node);
    $form_state['node'] = $node;
  }
  else {
    $node = $form_state['node'];
  }

  $form['#node_edit_form'] = TRUE;

  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'node-form';
  if (!empty($node->type)) {
    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'node-' . $node->type . '-form';
  }

  foreach (array('nid', 'vid', 'uid', 'created', 'type', 'language') as $key) {
    $form[$key] = array(
      '#type' => 'value', 
      '#value' => isset($node->$key) ? $node->$key : NULL,
    );
  }

  $form['changed'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden', 
    '#default_value' => isset($node->changed) ? $node->changed : NULL,
  );

  $function = node_type_get_base($node) . '_form';
  if (function_exists($function) && ($extra = $function($node, $form_state))) {
    $form = array_merge_recursive($form, $extra);
  }
  if (isset($form['title']) && !isset($form['title']['#weight'])) {
    $form['title']['#weight'] = -5;
  }

  $form['#node'] = $node;

  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#access' => variable_get('node_preview_' . $node->type, DRUPAL_OPTIONAL) != DRUPAL_REQUIRED || (!form_get_errors() && isset($form_state['node_preview'])), 
    '#value' => t('Save'), 
    '#weight' => 5, 
    '#submit' => array('node_form_submit'),
  );
  if (!empty($node->nid) && node_access('delete', $node)) {
    $form['actions']['delete'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit', 
      '#value' => t('Delete'), 
      '#weight' => 15, 
      '#submit' => array('node_form_delete_submit'),
    );
  }

  // Add the validation handlers.

  field_attach_form('node', $node, $form, $form_state, entity_language('node', $node));
  return $form;
}
```

This code is taken from [node_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7); it is a ripped off version that include only what necessary to allow to enter the title, the body content, and the values for any field implemented using the field API.
As you see, the code still need to define the form validation handler, and the form submission handler. You use the code of [node_form_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_validate/7) as guideline for your
validation handler.

The form builder can be used for a menu item as the following one.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mymodule/%node/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_node_form', 1), 
    'access arguments' => array('the permission users should have to see this menu item'), 
  );

  return $items;
}
```